# How to add custom user role into wordpress

Tags: php, users, user-roles

I added this code snippet to my function.php to create a user but after logging with this role I'm unable to edit the learndash course lessons quizzes...

```
add_role( 'learndash_content_manager', 'Learndash Content Manager', array(
    'read' => true,
    'manage_options' => true,
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'edit_others_posts' => true,
    'edit_files' => true,
    'publish_posts' => true,
    'delete_posts' => true,
    'delete_others_posts' => true,
    'manage_categories' => true,
    'edit_ld_courses' => true,
    'edit_ld_lessons' => true,
    'edit_ld_topics' => true,
    'edit_ld_quizzes' => true,
    'edit_ld_questions' => true,
    'manage_links' => true,
    'manage_options' => true,
    'post_manage_options' => true,
    'edit_published_ld_courses' => true
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
add_role('student', __(
        'Student'),
        array(
            'read'            => true, // Allows a user to read
            'create_posts'      => false, // Allows user to create new posts
            'edit_posts'        => false, // Allows user to edit their own posts
            'edit_others_posts' => false, // Allows user to edit others posts too
            'publish_posts' => false, // Allows the user to publish posts
            'manage_categories' => false, // Allows user to manage post categories
            )
     );
```

Please also consider removing admin bar for certain users:

```
function remove_admin_bar() {
    if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) {
        show_admin_bar(false);
    }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');
```

Take a look are your "ld" keys hooked right. If they are not, wp could clash.